# How to programattically update a form field value in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd version 4.0.0-rc.3, 
I have a form that contains the following values

```
{
   user: {
     address: {
        country: 'India',
        state: 'abc',
        zipcode: 123456
     }
   }
}
```

How can I update zipcode value into 98765?
**setFieldsValue** is updating fields in the root level only

i was trying with

```
setFieldsValue({
   ['user.address.zipcode']: 98765
})
```

result of this function is

```
{
   user: {
     address: {
        country: 'India',
        state: 'abc',
        zipcode: 123456
     }
   },
   user.address.zipcode:98765 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers

Comment: As per my understanding setFieldsValue is work for updating the filed value specifically.

Comment: If you want to update the value through the filed using setFieldsValue method, use field names like zipcode then get values through the form validator method, if I am wrong, provide a fiddle.

Comment: This code will work, but I have to do something based on the exact changed field, 
         setFieldsValue({
              user: {
                  address: {
                       country: 'India',
                       state: 'abc',
                      zipcode: 98765
                  }
           } 
})

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = {user: {...address, zipcode:98765 }}
```

Comment: please explain a little bit

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Edit the original answer with a textual explanation about your code snippet for future readers.

Comment: This answer is on the Low Quality Posts review queue because you didn't describe your answer. That wastes time of people scanning answers because they have to reverse engineer answers to figure out what they do and how they relate to the question. Please edit your answer and include a description of how your answer solves the problem to avoid deletion.

Answer (score 0):

use setFields

```
setFields([{
   name: ['user', 'address', 'zipcode'],
   value: 98765,
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper):

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

setFields(update(fields, {
  user: {
    address: {
      zipcode: {$set: 98765}
    }
  }
}))
```

or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
setFields({
  ...fields, // if there is only user inside the fields, that's not necessary
  user: {
    ...fields.user, // if there is only address inside the user, that's not necessary
    address: {
      ...fields.user.adress, // This will copy all the address attributes (country, state, zipcode)
      zipcode: 98765 // This will overwrite the zipcode
    }
  }
})
```

Either will set a copy of your previous state changing only the zipcode.